# How to create a new user when a UsernamePasswordValidator is used for authentication? WCF

Tags: wcf, authentication, client

A WCF web service is hosted in IIS and uses `wsHttpBinding` with `TransportWithMessageCredential` security mode. I handle the authentication by inheriting from the `UsernamePasswordValidator`. I have a WPF client which connects to the web service. In that client the user should be able to login or register if he doesn't have an account. The proxy can't call any methods on the service before it has passed authentication. I thought of creating a website for registration, but I would rather use the desktop application instead. My question is what are my options to enable registration? Is there a standard approach to this? Any tips/tricks much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create users using using ASP.Net Membership and Role providers (assuming you have hosted the service in IIS). 
 You can either create a registration portal using ASP.Net and its standard Login controls. Or you can create your own UI that calls WCF Authentication services which is a wrapper around the default asp.net membership provider.Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386582.aspx)